# reload list in component when subject is changes in service Angular 10

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I want to reload a list in my `component` when a change is made to the list. This list is stored in a `service` as an `BehaviourSubject`. I subscribe to the subject in my component which displays the list in an table. When a user clicks on an item in the list it opens a view through an `router`. This is where the user can perform some actions on this item (delete, edit/save etc.) but when an item is deleted it does delete it in the original list in the `service`, but it still shows that item in the component where the list is displayed. I thought a behaviour subject will be checked if changes are made and reload the list, but it does not seem to work.

my `service.ts`:

```
export class OfferService {
  offers: Offer[] = [];
  public offersSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Offer[]>(this.offers);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.generateRandomOffers();
   }

  private generateRandomOffers(): void {

    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      let offer = new Offer(this.offersSubject.getValue().length + 1);
      offer = Offer.createRandomOffer();
      this.offersSubject.getValue().push(offer);
    }

  }

  public FindAll(): Offer[] {
    return this.offersSubject.getValue();
  }

  // observable of offers list
  public getAll(): Observable<Offer[]> {
    return of(this.offersSubject.getValue());
  }


  public FindById(offerId: number): Offer {
    return this.offersSubject.getValue().find(o => o.id === offerId);
  }

  public Save(offer: Offer): Offer {
    let offerExist = false;
    const index = this.offersSubject.getValue().findIndex(o => o.id === offer.id);

    this.offersSubject.getValue().forEach( element => {
      if (element.id === offer.id)
      {
        element = offer;
        offerExist = true;
        this.offersSubject.getValue()[index] = element;
      }
    });

    if (!offerExist)
    {
      this.offersSubject.getValue().push(offer);
    }
    return this.offersSubject.getValue().find(o => o.id === offer.id);
  }

  public DeleteById(offerId: number): Offer {
    const deleteOffer = this.offersSubject.getValue().find(o => o.id === offerId);
    this.offers = this.offersSubject.getValue().filter(o => o.id !== offerId);
    this.offersSubject.next(this.offers);
    return deleteOffer;
  }

  public AddOffer(): void {
    let offer = new Offer(this.offers.length + 1);
    offer = Offer.createRandomOffer();
    this.offersSubject.getValue().push(offer);
  }
}
```

My `Component.ts` (where the list is displayed):

```
selectOfferViaRouter = false;
  offers: Offer[] = [];
  selectedOfferId = -1;
  trigger: any;

  constructor(
    private offerService: OfferService,
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllOffers();
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.getAllOffers();
  }

  // get all offers on observable
  getAllOffers(): void {
    this.offerService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.offers = data;
    });
  }

  // to update the table of offers
  detectTrigger(event: Event): void {
    this.getAllOffers();
    console.log(this.offers);
  }

  selectOffer(id: number): void {
    this.router.navigate([id], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
  }


  addOffer(): void{
    this.offerService.AddOffer();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continuously receive data from the stream you need to provide the same reference. In the service getOffer method, you need to return `this.offersSubject.asObservable();` This is read-only part of the same stream. When you want to update the stream then you call next on the origin stream. I already created some simple [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stream-crud)! :)

Comment: Thanks for the great help, I fixed it in my app thanks. The demo made me really understand it!